# Saving JPG format with PIL

Tags: django, heroku, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL to make thumbnails of images I upload and everything is fine with PNGs or GIFs. However, uploading JPGs is giving me a headache.  I kept getting a invalid format type for a while, and then I found this at the bottom of the JPG page on the PIL website...

> Note: To enable JPEG support, you need to build and install the IJG
>   JPEG library before building the Python Imaging Library. See the
>   distribution README for details.

Anyway, so I deployed to Heroku and for some reason it seems to be no longer giving me the invalid format error that I had been getting on my local... except even though there is now a photo object living in the db, I can't seem to access them.  I drop their location into into an image tag but I keep getting a broken image link symbol.

Here is what my override save looks like in models:

```
def save(self, force_update=False, force_insert=False, thumb_size=(90,150)):
    image = Image.open(self.image)

    if image.mode not in ('L', 'RGB'):
        image = image.convert('RGB')
    # save the original size
    self.image_width, self.image_height = image.size

    image.thumbnail(thumb_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # save the thumbnail to memory
    temp_handle = StringIO()

    image.save(temp_handle, format='JPEG')

    temp_handle.seek(0) # rewind the file
    # save to the thumbnail field
    suf = SimpleUploadedFile(os.path.split(self.image.name)[-1],
                            temp_handle.read(),
                            content_type='image/jpg')
    self.thumbnail.save(suf.name, suf, save=False)
    self.thumbnail_width, self.thumbnail_height = image.size


    #save the image object
    super(Photo, self).save(force_update, force_insert)
```

Comment: You're dealing with two different environents, so the two symptoms aren't related. On your local machine, you're missing the libjpeg libraries, so PIL was compiled without JPEG suppport. To fix that you only need to install those libraries, uninstall PIL and then reinstall it so it can build JPEG support. Your problems on Heroku are unrelated.

Comment: Yeah, totally, then in that case what I'm concerned about is getting it to work on Heroku.  I can mock things up with PNGs on my local, but I want it to take JPGs on my deployment.

Comment: I can't spot anything "wrong" with the code you have. I would suggest getting PIL set up properly on your local machine and see if you then have a similar problem there as on Heroku. That will at least point to whether it's a problem with your code or something Heroku related.

Comment: PIL seems to be working on heroku since when I change the format to PNG everything works fine, image and thumbnail are saved.

Comment: as @ChrisPratt and the error you copied say, PIL must be COMPILED with jpeg support - basically install libjpeg than build again.